# SQL how to replace all (Varied) texts in a text column with a single default text?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin

For some reason this isn't working - maybe I need to escape some of these characters in my text string that I'm trying to do the REPLACE() on? I also thought that using the % wildcard to select all texts for replacing might not be working, but I'm not sure what an alternative solution might be!

Here's the SQL I'm trying to run to replace all text values in the column with a single, default text:

```
Update `table_name`
Set `field_name` = Replace(`field_name` , '%','{"notifyEmailSystem":1,"privacyProfileView":0,"privacyPhotoView":0,"privacyFriendsView":0,"privacyGroupsView":"","privacyVideoView":0,"notifyEmailMessage":1,"notifyEmailApps":1,"notifyWallComment":0}')
```

Comment: ... what? You want to replace a column's value with a default text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Replace`, you can `Update`the column directly

#### Update statement

```
Update `table_name`
Set `field_name` = '{"notifyEmailSystem":1,"privacyProfileView":0,"privacyPhotoView":0,"privacyFriendsView":0,"privacyGroupsView":"","privacyVideoView":0,"notifyEmailMessage":1,"notifyEmailApps":1,"notifyWallComment":0}'
```